# How can I pass multiple places seperated by commas from the following multipart form?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, form-data

My html form is

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" v-on:submit.prevent="handelSubmit($event);">
  <div class="clear">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Offer <small>(required)</small></label>
        <input type="file" name="offer" accept="image/*" required="">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Place :</label>
          <select id="basics" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Select Place" name="places" ref="place" multiple="">
        <option v-for="post in places" v-bind:value="post.id" >{{post.name}}</option>
                                                            </select>
        </div>
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-finish btn-primary' name='finish' value='Finish' />
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My vue js code is

```
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
           var form = e.target; // Get hold of the form element from the event
           var fd = new FormData(form); // create a FormData
           fd.append('auth-token',this.authType)
           fd.append('post',this.postId)

           console.log(...fd);
            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/alpha/add/offer/',
              data: fd,
              type: 'POST',
              processData: false,  // Important!
              contentType: false,
              success: function(e) {
              if (e.status)
              {

                $("#alertModal").modal('show');
              $(".alert").removeClass("hidden").html("Your Offer has been successfully added");


            }
              else {

               alert("Registration Failed") 
              }
          }
            });
            return false;
},
```

I need to select multiple places which is ok for me. I need to send these multiple places seperated by commas. How can I able to send these places seperated by commas, now it is sending one by one. I need to send places seperated by commas. Please help me to obatin the same.

Or else Is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see you using v-model in your html. Just, using v-model will solve your problem:

```
// ...
data() {
  return {
   selectedValues: []
  }
}
```

Now, when you use `v-model="selectedValues"` in your `select` html , vue will automatically store the selected values in `selectedValues` and now you have array of selected values and this way you can post them by using `join()` method: (construct this in your form data)

```
this.selectedValues.join(', ');
```

---

You can also check [example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select) in vue documentation.

Comment: sir, then how will i upload image

Comment: sir, how will i upload image in this case? can you please help

Comment: Your code works fine, just make changes what I have mentioned.

Comment: fd.append('place',this.place.join(', '));

Comment: is it fine sir??

Comment: sir, if i done this way, ------WebKitFormBoundary8q4BorTkY2esnxik
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="place[]"

5
------WebKitFormBoundary8q4BorTkY2esnxik
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="place[]"

6
------WebKitFormBoundary8q4BorTkY2esnxik
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="place[]"

11
------WebKitFormBoundary8q4BorTkY2esnxik
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="place[]"

14

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundary8q4BorTkY2esnxik
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="place"

5, 6, 11, 14

Comment: both of this is happening sir??

Answer (score -1):

I think you can workaround it using a hidden field with a computed value.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: []
  },
  computed: {
    commaSeparated() {
      return this.value.join();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>Muiltiple</label>
  <br/>
  <select v-model="value" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input :value="commaSeparated" type="hidden" />
  {{commaSeparated}}
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to use tricky way. Just simply v-model will be a solution.

Comment: sir, then how will i upload image

Comment: This approach works fine with regular form data. If you need to upload a image just put a `<input type="file"/>` and let the native form submition do the work.